# Can colorblind people see any types of images that normally sighted people have a hard time with?

Tags: eye, vision

Could one devise a first image that contained a "hidden" sub-image where said sub-image is such that colorblind people would typically have an easier time seeing said sub-image embedded within said first image than a normally sighted person

"Can i hide a picture of my cat inside another picture so that only my colorblind son could see the cat, as a way to empower him?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, in fact there is a '[Reverse Color Blind Test](https://www.moillusions.com/reverse-color-blindness-test/)' that is difficult for normal sighted people to pass but is relatively easy for colorblind people to pass. Here's an example:

[image]

BTW, the word is "NO"